# Are there any security vulnerabilities with domain email forwarding?

Tags: email

I recently bought a domain through CheapName.com which offers free email forwarding. I would like to use it to have a unique email for every account I make online (because it can be set up so all emails with your domain are forwarded to a catch-all email address).

Would email forwarding cause any security issues that wouldn't normally arise from an email being sent straight to a yahoo email account for example?